# Mocking of extension method result in System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, .net-core, mocking, moq, extension-methods

I'm unit testing a ClientService that uses the `IMemoryCache` interface:

ClientService.cs:

```
public string Foo()
{        
    //... code

    _memoryCache.Set("MyKey", "SomeValue", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60));
}
```

When I try to mock the `IMemoryCache`'s `Set` extension with:

```
AutoMock mock = AutoMock.GetLoose();

var memoryCacheMock = _mock.Mock<IMemoryCache>();

string value = string.Empty;

// Attempt #1:
memoryCacheMock
     .Setup(x => x.Set<string>(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<TimeSpan>()))
     .Returns("");

// Attempt #2:
memoryCacheMock
    .Setup(x => x.Set(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<TimeSpan>()))
    .Returns(new object());
```

It throw an exception of:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression: x =>
>   x.Set(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny(),
>   It.IsAny())
>       Extension methods (here: CacheExtensions.Set) may not be used in setup / verification ex

This is the Cache extension of the namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`

```
public static class CacheExtensions
{
   public static TItem Set<TItem>(this IMemoryCache cache, object key, TItem value, TimeSpan absoluteExpirationRelativeToNow);
}
```

Comment: You cannot mock extension method, I guess behind the `Set` is actually `CreateEntry` which actually should have been mocked...

Comment: Extension methods are static - you can't mock static methods. There are some tools that let you replace them, I think, but that's not the right approach IMHO. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580015/how-to-mock-static-methods-in-c-sharp-using-moq-framework).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Extension methods are actually static methods and they cannot be mocked using **`moq`**. What you could mock are the methods used by the extension method itself...

In your case `Set` uses `CreateEntry` which is the method defined by `IMemoryCache` and it could be mocked. Try something like this:

```
memoryCacheMock
    .Setup(x => x.CreateEntry(It.IsAny<object>()))
    .Returns(Mock.Of<ICacheEntry>);
```

Comment: How about the Get method? I'm assuming it's the TryGetValue method?

Comment: @JoshMonreal You are correct.