# How to choose the correct overload (Generic T / object)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, extension-methods

I'm trying to mock the `IMemoryCache` interface.

The `IMemoryCache` interface looks like:

```
public interface IMemoryCache : IDisposable
{
    //...
    bool TryGetValue(object key, out object value);
    //...
}
```

And the `ImemoryCache` has an extension method (namespace `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` of:

```
public static class CacheExtensions
{
    public static bool TryGetValue<TItem>(this IMemoryCache cache, object key, out TItem value);
}
```

The mocking process is:

```
AutoMock mock = AutoMock.GetLoose();

string access_token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

var memoryCacheMock = mock.Mock<IMemoryCache>();
memoryCacheMock
    .Setup(x => x.TryGetValue(It.IsAny<object>(), out access_token))
    .Returns(true);
```

I'm trying to mock the `TryGetValue` method of the interface (not the extension method), but it automatically refers to the extension (it is not [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57705394/6844481) to mock an extension method).

When I hover the `TryGetValue` it show that it is referring to the extension:
[image]

How to make the setup of `TryGetValue` refer to the overloaded interface method?

### Edit:

Changing the `string` into `object` make it worked, but why? the string is a type of object.

Comment: try changing access_token's type to object?

Comment: Why are you even trying to mock the extension method in the first place? Mock the relevant bits of `IMemoryCache` and the extension method will call them.

Comment: Hey @DavidG, I'm not trying to mock the extension method, only the method of the interface

Comment: @BarışAkkurt It works, but why? string is an object

Comment: Sorry, slightly misread the question. You need to make the second parameter an object. Because you are giving it a string, it uses the extension instead.

Comment: @ShaharShokrani See if this works https://stackoverflow.com/a/42387886/5233410 . If it does then its a duplicate.