# Mocking an Interface returns System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, moq, .net-6.0

I am trying to mock a Interface method, but I am getting this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: obj => obj.ReadInStreamAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IList<string>>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
Extension methods (here: ComputerVisionClientExtensions.ReadInStreamAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
```

This is my code:

```
var computerVisionClientMock = new Mock<IComputerVisionClient>();

computerVisionClientMock.Setup(obj => obj.ReadInStreamAsync(
                                    It.IsAny<Stream>(),
                                    It.IsAny<string>(),
                                    It.IsAny<IList<string>>(),
                                    It.IsAny<string>(),
                                    It.IsAny<string>(),
                                    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
                                    ).Result).Callback<Stream, string, IList<string>, string, string, CancellationToken>((var0, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5) => { Thread.Sleep(2000); });
```

This is the Interface's definition:

[IComputerVisionClient Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.icomputervisionclient?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Per the error, you cannot mock extension methods. You can only mock the methods actually defined in the interface. It's likely the extension method calls `ReadInStreamWithHttpMessagesAsync` (though you'd have to decompile to be sure), so consider mocking that instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking of extension method result in System.NotSupportedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57705394/mocking-of-extension-method-result-in-system-notsupportedexception)