# Mocking a current logged in user for unit testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking

I need to mock current logged in user for testing the following function. This function returns the id of the current logged in user from the Users table in the database.

```
  public static string CurrentUser()
    {
        string loginuser= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        if(loginuser != "")
        {
            using (var cntx = new EdmxEntities())
            {
                return cntx.Users.Where(s => s.Email == loginuser).Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
        return loginuser;

    }
```

(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) This function returns the current logged in username but returns null during testing which throws an Null Reference Exception.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `mock` a `static method` in your typical mocking framework. Depending on something like a database also means you are not `unit testing`. A `unit test` cannot depend on dependencies from the *infrastructure*.

What you could do (and should do IMO) is either:

- Create an `interface` that captures the functionality of returning the current user which you can then `mock` using your framework of choice. This interface (with a matching instance of an implementation of this `interface`) could then be injected into the class where you need it.
- Or, when you prefer `static methods`, ask for the `dependency` of the current user in the place where you need it and inject it directly from your `dependency injection` setup.

If you don't care about all this you could probably setup a test database with a `connectionString` to that in your test project. You would then be `integration testing`, which has its own merits.

There are however ways to do what you ask (but I would not recommend this), check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12580110/2877982