# How to pass my DbContext object for testing using xunit and moq

Tags: .net-core, moq, xunit.net

Below mentioned is the test function that checks if details exist for the particular transactionId.

```
        [Fact]
        public async Task GetAllBlobDetails_Test()
        {
           _serviceScopeFactory.Setup(x => x.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MriDbContext>()).Returns(_context);
           BlobStatusEntity blobStatusEntity =  await _bspRepository.GetBlobDetails("123");
           Assert.NotNull(blobStatusEntity)
        }
```

where  _serviceScopeFactory is

```
Mock<IServiceScopeFactory> _serviceScopeFactory = new Mock<IServiceScopeFactory>();
(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection)
```

In the above function it calls _bspRepository.GetBlobDetails for particular transactionId ("123")

So here is the definition for GetBlobDetails

```
 public async Task<BlobStatusEntity> GetBlobDetails(string transactionId)
        {

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(transactionId))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transactionId));
                }

                MriDbContext mriDbcontext = _scopeFactory.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MriDbContext>();

                return await mriDbContext.BlobStatus.FirstOrDefaultAsync(ele => ele.TransactionId == transactionId);
        }
```

where _scopeFactory is `IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory` which is injected from the constructor.

When I am running the above test function GetAllBlobDetails_Test, I am getting the following error like this.

```
Message: 
    System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: ... => ....GetRequiredService<MriDbContext>()
    Extension methods (here: ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
```

I am new to moq and xunit.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In test code, I am using an in-memory database and I created my context which is linked to in-memory database instead of the using real database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the initialization part

```
  private BspRepository _bspRepository;
        private Mock<IServiceScopeFactory> _serviceScopeFactory;
        private Mock<ILogger<BspRepository>> _logger;
        private Mock<IMapper> _mapper;
        private DbContextOptions<MriDbContext> _options;
        private MriDbContext _context;
        private Mock<IServiceProvider> _serviceProvider;
        private Mock<IServiceScope> _serviceScope;
        public BSPRepositoryTests()
        {
            _serviceScopeFactory = new Mock<IServiceScopeFactory>();
            _logger = new Mock<ILogger<BspRepository>>();
            _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
            _serviceProvider = new Mock<IServiceProvider>();
            _serviceScope = new Mock<IServiceScope>();
            _options = SetupDBContext();
            _context = new MriDbContext(_options);
            _bspRepository = new BspRepository(_serviceScopeFactory.Object, _logger.Object, _mapper.Object);
            SetupData();
            SetupServices();

        }
```

I resolved my error by mocking objects in this way

```
 private void SetupServices()
        {
            _serviceProvider.Setup(x => x.GetService(typeof(MriDbContext))).Returns(_context);
            _serviceScope.Setup(x => x.ServiceProvider).Returns(_serviceProvider.Object);
            _serviceScopeFactory.Setup(x => x.CreateScope())
                .Returns(_serviceScope.Object);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

So the root cause here is that you can't mock an extension method in Moq

You're doing this here:

```
 _serviceScopeFactory.Setup(x => x.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MriDbContext>()).Returns(_context);
```

`GetRequiredService<T>` is an extension method that extends `IServiceProvider` which you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getrequiredservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Depending on what the specific case you're trying to test is (are you testing the context creation, or the actual write to the DB?), you should be able to re-write your test to avoid mocking the extension method and mocking the public instance methods being used instead.  You could even mock the actual instance method on `IServiceProvider` if you really wanted to keep the existing structure.

Further discussion of this topic exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12580015/7385884). That question uses MSTest rather than XUnit, but your issue here is specific to Moq.