# Unit Testing a method which contains a Using block

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have a already written (was written years ago) C# function, I have been asked to cover this method with Unit Tests.

```
public string PlaceOrder(int requestId, string orderedby)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DatabaseContext dbContext = new DatabaseContext("myConnectionStringHere"))
            {
                var req = dbContext.Orders.Where(row => row.id == requestId).FirstOrDefault();
                if (req == null)
                    return "not found";
               
                req.status="A";
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                return "found";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

Now while Unit testing I need to make sure that it does not write anything to database, so I have to `MOQ` it.
How can I `MOQ`, it contains `Using` block.

I know architecture could have been better and design patterns should have been followed but I am not allowed to change the structure of the application as it is a legacy application.

Comment: This legacy code is tightly coupled to the actual database  and cannot be easily isolated from affecting the actual database without being refactored. This is a good example of technical debt.

Comment: I am up for refactoring as long as it does not involves big changes

Comment: The `using` statement isn't the problem here. `using` only means that the class implements `IDisposable`, not that it can't be unit tested.

Comment: Refactoring the production code is the only way to test it. But there's not enough info here to suggest exactly how to refactor. We would need to see more about the class of which this is a method. In particular, where does `intgContext` come from?

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to clarify in what way `using` prevents you from adding unit test to this method? As @DanielMann said it should not impact ability to write unit tests in any way.

Comment: To clarify my question, Unit testing is not the problem here. I need `moq` the `dbContext` which is being used inside `using` statement. Mocking is challenge here not the Unit Testing.

Comment: @vndpal Mocking is used for unit testing. As prior comments have stated, the root issue here is that you have tightly-coupled code that is not written in such a way as to be mockable, and thus not unit testable. The problem has **nothing** to do with the presence of a `using` statement.

Comment: can you elaborate more on the tightly-coupled? and what would you do on the above snippet to make it more loosely-coupled and thus "more unit testable"?

Comment: Which EF version are you using?

Comment: EF version 5.0.0

Comment: Do you want to unit test it by mocking the DbContext or do you want to integration test it by using in memory or sqlite option?

Comment: Unit test by mocking DbContext

Comment: You can take a look on running the db context on memory during the unit tests...  `new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext.myDbContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Options);` then just seeding some data (inyect the needed test data) an run your order method.

Answer (score 1):

The general guidance here is to prefer Integration Test with in memory (w/o sqlite) database over unit testing.

Let me suggest you four helper libraries which can make your testing easier:

#### EntityFrameworkCoreMock

[Github link](https://github.com/cup-of-tea-dot-be/entity-framework-core-mock)

The prerequisite here is to mark your `DbSet` as `virtual` like this:

```
public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

Then you can create a mock where you can populate your `Orders` collection with some dummy data:

```
var initialOrders = new[]
{
    new Order { ... },
    new Order { ... },
};

var dbContextMock = new DbContextMock<DatabaseContext>(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DatabaseContext>().Options);
var ordersDbSetMock = dbContextMock.CreateDbSetMock(db => db.Orders, initialOrders);
```

You have to rewrite your containing class of the `PlaceOrder` method in a way to receive a `DatabaseContext` parameter in the constructor to be able inject `dbContextMock.Object` during testing.

In the assertion phase you can query your data and make assertion against it. Since you do not call `Add`, `Remove` or any other CRUD method, you can only `Verify` the `SaveChanges` call.

```
public void GivenAnExistingOrder_WhenICallPlaceOrder_ThenSaveChangesIsCalledOnce()
{
   ...
   //Assert
   dbMock.Verify(db => db.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);
}

public void GivenANonExistingOrder_WhenICallPlaceOrder_ThenSaveChangesIsCalledNever()
{
   ...
   //Assert
   dbMock.Verify(db => db.SaveChanges(), Times.Never);
}
```

#### `EntityFrameworkCore.Testing`

[Github link](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing)

It is working more or less in the way as the previous library.

```
var dbContextMock = Create.MockedDbContextFor<DatabaseContext>();
dbContextMock.Set<Order>().AddRange(initialOrders);
dbContextMock.SaveChanges();
```

The assertions work in the same way.

---

A 3rd (less mature) library is called [Moq.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/MichalJankowskii/Moq.EntityFrameworkCore).

---

If you really keen to perform unit testing by avoiding in memory database then you should give a try to the [`MockQueryable`](https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable) library.

```
const int requestId = 1;
var orders = new List<Order>();
var ordersMock = orders.AsQueryable().BuildMockDbSet();
ordersMock.Setup(table => table.Where(row => row.Id == requestId)).Returns(...)
```

Here you are basically mocking what should be the result of your `Where` filter. In order to be able to use this the containing class of the `PlaceOrder` should receive a `DbSet<Order>` parameter via its constructor.

Or if you have an `IDatabaseContext` interface then you can use that one as well like this:

```
Mock<IQueryable<Order>> ordersMock = orders.AsQueryable().Build();
Mock<IDatabaseContext> dbContextMock = ...
dbContextMock.Setup(m => m.ReadSet<Order>()).Returns(ordersMock.Object));
```

Answer (score 0):

Many things should be changed here:

1:

Do not implement your connection string this way, directly in the code base.
Instead, DI your database into your classes.

so this pseudo code should help out with the general idea.

```
public void ConfigureService(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
   ...

  
   string connectionString = //secure storage;
   serviceCollection.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => {

      options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

   });

   ...
}
```

And then

```
public class OrderRepository
{
        
   private IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory ;
        
   public OrderRepository(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory ){
      _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory ;
   }
   
   ...
        
        
   public string PlaceOrder(int requestId, string orderedby)
   {
      try
      {
         using (var context = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
         {
            var req = context.Orders.Where(row => row.id == requestId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (req == null)
               return "not found";
                       
            req.status="A";
            context.SaveChanges();
            return "found";
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         return "error";
      }
   }
    
   ...

}
```

if you want to make an integration test, you can then use an InMemory db to emulate whatever you want.
Or you can connect to a "real" db, and do it that way.

If you want to make it a unit test, you can see at this link:
[How to setup a DbContext Mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62897718/how-to-pass-my-dbcontext-object-for-testing-using-xunit-and-moq)

2:

returning a string saying found/not found for a order being placed, seems extremely counter productive.

if your aim is to log this information, provider a DI logger, that can log this. (Try importing the ILogger interface, it's a microsoft extension on logging, can't remember the nuget package  name)
should enable you to log with DI very efficiently.

If your aim is to let a possible UI display this message, there is no way the message content should originate from back-end or domain logic.

At least not like this.

Then you should make an interface for a response, and return an implementation of said interface, that exists somewhere else as a minimum but even that is a bit like peeing your pants.
(And contains a UI friendly message, can contain a possible stacktrace/exception), and other possible relevant information, like what Id you were trying to place an order on etc.)

You should make it something that happens at the interface between your UI and domain logic, provided that is what the string is intended for. Where you would expect to see  error handling.

3:
WTF is up with the catch? you just return error? Well ? What error? you lose the stack-trace this way?
Someone should be punished for that.