# How to mock static method in static class in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to mock the value of Utils.IsLocalEnv to be false. How can I do it using C# in unit tests?
I tried this:  `Utils.IsLocalEnv = () => true;` but get wrong.

```
    public static class Utils
    {
        public static bool IsLocalEnv()
        {
            if (aspNetCoreEnv.ToLower() == "development")
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
     }
```

Comment: side note : your method can be simplified to `return aspNetCoreEnv.ToLower() == "development";`

Comment: Some options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580015/how-to-mock-static-methods-in-c-sharp-using-moq-framework